# Thin php proxy?

Tags: php, proxy

I have a basic proxy like php script requirement. I need to create some php script like getcookie.php which actually sends request to "target" server.

I already have "target" server serving a response with a cookie. Is there a way where I can simply forward the whole response object from "target" back to the client in php script?

Blunt way is to build a response object copying the cookie info from "target" into response object cookie.

It would save me a lot of time if I could just forward the whole response object back to browser from the php script.

Please let me know any easy way to deal with this.

Thanks ,
Lalith

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. I found answer to my question. Basically I chose the easy way out if this.

PHP thin client will just request the other server for a cookie. The other server returns it as a data.

This PHP client will set cookie with this data and respond back to browser.

- Lalith